# Fetching selected rows in jsp tables when submitting a form

Tags: jsp

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="Approve">Approve/Decline</td>
```

This repeat for no.of rows(say 4) I return from DB. All 4 rows got same checkbox name and when I check the 2 and 3rd checkbox, it should return those row values alone.

```
String[] choice=request.getParameterValues("choice");
if(choice!=null){
                for(int i=0;i<choice.length;i++){
                    out.println("<p> " + choice[i] +i+ "</p>");
                    }
```

This I am submitting using a form and I need to retrieve properly those selected rows alone.

How to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Don't use "Approve" as the value of the checkbox. Use the ID if the row.

Comment: ok but if I checked the checkbox in 2nd and 3rd, it gets the count of checked checkbox and it returns 0 and 1(as count is 2) .. not 2 and 3

Comment: Why would you count the checkboxes? If you display a row with ID 542, a second row with ID 743 and a third row with ID 1542, and the checkbox values are thus respectively 542, 743 and 1542, then checking the second and third checkbox will submit a parameter choice with value [743, 1542], and that's what you want, isn't it? Know the IDs of the selected rows.

Comment: Yes mostly I need that kind.. but not working with above code..

Comment: The most appropriate method is to get values in servlet, not in JSP and if you have the possibility to index those records you can use that index along with ID returned by the parameter names. Otherwise you have no chances to achieve the same goal.

Comment: @SRIRAMRAMACHANDRAN of course it does not work with the above code, since all the checkboxes have the same value: "Approve". As I said, the value of the checkbox must be the ID of the row. Not "Approve".

Comment: Please share your code for the loop where you output approve checkbox.